# Difference beween: character >= '0' and character <= 0

Tags: java

I am trying to find out in my code if char is digit or not.

What is difference between:

```
character >= 0 && character <= 9
```

And:

```
character >= '0' && character <= '9'
```

Because both have a different outcome (I have got tests and their results changed if I write it in another way).

Thank you!

Comment: `0` is the literal value zero. `'0'` is the _character_ '0' whose ASCII value is 48.

Comment: A `char` may be a single digit, but it also has a corresponding `int` value, which allows to do both of your example lines. Those values are different, find out about that in [an ASCII table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html).

Comment: Consider [Character::isDigit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char))

Comment: Treating a character like an integer means that you are interpreting its raw [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) value.  Note that the character `'0'` is actually represented by the integer `48`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing chars in java you are comparing them by their ascii value. So '0' has a value of 48 and '9' has a value of 57.

```
character >= '0' && character <= '9'
```

is the same as

```
character >= 48 && character <= 57
```

Comment: I think it was tagged as javascript when I wrote my answer but the content does not change based on the language in this case